# COUNTIF option for "Other"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data for different cities, Nottingham, London, Derby, Oxford, etc.

and I am doing COUNTIFS that look like this

```
=COUNTIF(MySheet!$N:$N,"Nottingham")
```

Basically I want to have a last countif that is "other" so anything that is not on the places I already mentioned then is counted here

```
=COUNTIF(MySheet!N:N"Every other city")
```

Basically, how can I do this without having to go <> Nottingham, <>Derby, <>Oxford and like that for all of the cities that I have?

Comment: Do a count of all the data using COUNTA and subtract the sum of the cities you already calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula is basically what Rory said:

```
=COUNTA($N:$N)-COUNTIF(MySheet!$N:$N,"Nottingham")-COUNTIF(MySheet!$N:$N,"Derby")-COUNTIF(MySheet!$N:$N,"Oxford")-XXX

Where XXX = the number of cells in column N that contain
            something that is not a city name such as a 
            column header
```

Alternatively if you had the list of city names a column headers from P to R and other in column S you could do the following

Place the following in P2 and copy to the right

```
=COUNTIF(MySheet!$N:$N,P1)
```

In S2 place the following formula:

```
=COUNTA($N:$N)-sum(P2:R2)-XXX
```